# Can I send videos to android devices using gcm?

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, google-cloud-messaging

If not please suggest me how to send videos to android devices using c#. Earlier I have succeeded using gcm I easily sent out pushnotifications to android devices. My doubt is can I sent videos to android devices using gcm?

Comment: Not possible. GCM has a payload size limit which is not enough for a video.

Comment: Then how is it possible? any alternatives

Answer (score 0):

As per my earlier comment, it is not possible to send large files via GCM (nor FCM) due to the [payload size limit](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm).

What I think you can use instead is make use of [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/), store the video from there, in the push notification, you can send a download URL, which your client app should handle.